# How to do IIR filter when most of the coefficients are zero

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I what to do some audio effect in Python. For example, the simplest echo effect formula:

```
y[n] = x[n] + k*y[n-1000]
```

This is an IIR filter, and can be calculated by lfilter() in scipy.signal:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import scipy.signal as signal

pulse = np.zeros(10000)
pulse[0] = 1.0

a = np.zeros(1000)
a[[0,999]] = 1, -0.7

start = time.clock()
out = signal.lfilter([1], a, pulse)
print time.clock() - start

import pylab as pl
pl.plot(out)
pl.show()
```

The problem is: most of the coefficients of a are zero, and the filter can be calculated very quickly, but lfilter() can't realize this, and use all the zero coefficients.

I know I can code some particular calculation for this simplest example, but I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: There is nothing in numpy/scipy that would help here (besides lfilter), and I don't know of any other package that would do this. I think cython is the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import scipy
import scipy.signal as sig
import time

# Input signal.
x = scipy.randn(50000)

# Filter coefficients.
a = scipy.zeros(1001)
a[[0,-1]] = [1, -0.7]

# Method using lfilter.
start = time.clock()
y0 = sig.lfilter([1], a, x)
end = time.clock() - start
print end

# Method using for loop.
start = time.clock()
y1 = x
for i in range(1000, y1.size):
    y1[i] += 0.7*y1[i-1000]
end = time.clock() - start
print end

# Check that both outputs are equal.
print scipy.square(y0-y1).sum()
```

On my laptop: 0.38 seconds for method 1, **0.13** seconds for method 2.

Note: For delay of N samples, you must set `a[N]`, not `a[N-1]`.

Comment: thanks, I know for loop in python is faster than lfilter in this case. but for loop is slow. I am looking for some library to do this. If none, than I will try to do this in cython.